# Finder.app previews of aliases and symbolic links

Tags: snow-leopard, macos, finder, icon

I have a folder with Finder aliases and symbolic links (i.e. created using `ln -s original.pdf link.pdf`).

How can I make sure Finder displays previews for these instead of the standard icon?

This related to folder/icon view (CMD+1), not any QuickLook view.

Comment: What kind of preview do you mean? When I make an alias of a PDF file I can see a preview of the original file in the inspector and in the "spacebar preview". I'm guessing you mean the icon in a finder window.

Comment: Yes, the icon in the Finder window.

Comment: You can't... the alias does not hold this information and Finder does not initially go to the original file to get the preview.
When you quicklook or double click the app (quicklook is a small app) traverses the alias and goes to read the original file.

Comment: Why on earth would Finder not follow the symlink or alias to get the preview?  That doesn't make any sense, because if I have a directory with 100 files, I'm not going to quicklook each one, I expect to just look at the icon.